# Локальные имена во вложенных функциях

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется некий код:

```
def aaa():
    t = "text"

    def bbb():
        print(t)

    return bbb


v = aaa()
v()
```

В теле функции ааа создается функция bbb и она возвращается. Я не могу понять 2ух моментов:
1. Почему вызов V() не вызывает ошибку, ведь обхект функции должен уничтожится после выхода из тела.
2. Почему не уничтожается переменная t = "text"? Причина та-же самая ведь

Comment: Никто не должен уничтожиться, потому что с функцией `def bbb()` вы автоматически создали **замыкание** и затем поместили эту функцию в переменной `v`, так что успешно сохранились и функция, и замыкание, и переменная `t` в этом замыкании

Comment: Собственно, значение `t` можно обнаружить хранящимся в `v.__closure__[0].cell_contents`

Comment: В книге что я читаю нет и слова про "Замыкание". Что это?

Comment: Функция «помнит» окружающее её локальное пространство имён, в том числе переменную `t` в этом пространстве имён — в этом суть замыкания

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект уничтожается только тогда, когда перестает быть нужным кому либо, в `CPython` это происходит, когда количество ссылок на объект становится равным нулю.

`v` в данном примере - замыкание, имеющее доступ как к своим именам (в этом примере их нет), так и к именам внутри функции `aaa` (т.е. `t`, `bbb`), других более внешних функций (тоже нет) и к глобальным именам относительно того места, в котором функция была объявлена, (т.е. `aaa`, `v`)

Замыкание это функция, которая захватила переменные функции ее породившей, или функций еще выше в иерархии, и имеет возможность с ними работать, даже если та функция уже завершилась.

Примеры:

```py
def aaa(x):
    def bbb(y):
        def ccc(z):
            return x + y * z
        return ccc
    return bbb

print(aaa(5)(6)(7)) # 47
```

```py
def message(secret):
    def helper():
        return f'Никто кроме меня не знает, что secret={secret!r}'
    return helper

f1 = message("password")
f2 = message("hack the internet")

print(f1()) # Никто кроме меня не знает, что secret='password'
print(f2()) # Никто кроме меня не знает, что secret='hack the internet'
```

```
def notinlist(lst):
    def helper(x):
        return x not in lst
    return helper

print(*filter(notinlist([1,3]), range(10))) # 0 2 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

И все то же самое, но с помощью анонимных "лямбда"-функций

```py
def aaa(x):
    return lambda y: lambda z: x + y * z
```

```py
def notinlist(lst):
    return lambda x: x not in lst
```

```py
def message(secret):
    return lambda: f'Никто кроме меня не знает, что secret={secret!r}'
```

Comment: То есть как я понял переменная t не уничтожается потому что функция bbb ссылается на неё, а переменная v ссылается на bb?

Comment: Если упрощенно, то да, притом если в `aaa` будут другие переменные, до которых `bbb` нет дела - они вполне могут умереть с завершением `aaa`. И хоть это и не совсем так в реализации, проще считать, что при каждом __вызове__ `aaa`, создается новый экземпляр функции `bbb`, которая захватывает актуальные для этого вызова данные из вышестоящего контекста, как во втором моем примере - `f1` и `f2` указывают на разные функции, которые имеют доступ к разным `secret`

Comment: Немного подкорректировал ответ, потому, что замыкание захватывает данные не по ссылкам а по именам.